# Why Symbol's value as variable is void: haskell-mode-map?

Tags: haskell, emacs

I am config a haskell environment with this [installation-from-git-repository](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode#installation-from-git-repository):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "path/of/haskell-mode/")
(require 'haskell-mode-autoloads)
(add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list "path/of/haskell-mode/")
```

and add a key for navigate:

```
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "<f8>") 'haskell-navigate-imports)
```

But when I open emacs, a error occurred :
`Symbol's value as variable is void: haskell-mode-map`

I can't download haskell-mode form package central because of network can't connected. So I build it form source code.

Hope some help.

Comment: You need to first load the library that defines `haskell-mode-map`. And if loading it does not define the map (which it probably does not) then you need to evaluate the code that does. Typically, turning on the mode defines the map. A simple solution is typically to put your key binding definition inside an `eval-after-load` (or an `with-eval-after-load`), so that it is evaluated after the relevant code is loaded that defines the map.

Comment: @Drew, I add `(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode (load-library "haskell-mode"))` refer form [LoadingLispFiles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadingLispFiles) and so happy it works.Thanks your tips!